# How do I install a package found on ubuntu packages but apt-get cannot locate it?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm on an ubuntu OS installed on a chromebook and I'm trying to install pygame's dependencies.

One of them is timgm6mb-soundfont

You can see it on ubuntu packages here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/timgm6mb-soundfont

when I try `sudo apt-get install timgm6mb-soundfont`

I get "E: Unable to locate package timgm6mb-soundfont"

I read this article: [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file/1030)

about installing packages manually, but A they recommend that I always install using apt and B the files I find on ubuntu packages don't seem to have readme and install files.

This guy: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343626/how-do-i-install-timgm6mb-soundfont

seems to have had the same problem, I blindly tried his fix and it did not work (and I undid the fix).

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What’s your Ubuntu version? Per https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=timgm6mb-soundfont the package should be available in all _supported_ versions but are you running a supported Ubuntu version actually?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Guess it's not supported, right?

It's the only dependency stopping me from installing pygame. Is there some substitute? Or am I just not going to be able to install on 14.04LTS?

Answer (score 2):

You are running unsupported Ubuntu 14.04, so you'll have reinstall the OS. If you do reinstall Ubuntu, selecting 19.04 will make it easier to install PyGame (for Python 3), because it's included in the default repositories for Ubuntu 19.04 and later.

To install PyGame for Python 3.x on Ubuntu 19.04 and later, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pygame
```

To install PyGame for Python 2.x in Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-pygame
```